# Can't establish SSH connection in systemd.service

Tags: ssh, services

I created following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Server Tunneling
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=ssh -R server-login:80:localhost:8003 serveo.net
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `sudo systemctl start server-tunnels`. However, when I run `sudo systemctl status server-tunnels`, it says the service failed:

```
server-tunnels.service - Server Tunneling
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/server-tunnels.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-25 17:43:40 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 17139 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -R server-login:80:localhost:8003 serveo.net (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 17139 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
```

Of course, running `ssh -R server-login:80:localhost:8003 serveo.net` in a normal terminal works.

---

Changes I made according to @kuzeyron:

```
[Unit]
Description=Server Tunneling
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=
ExecStart=ssh -R server-login:80:localhost:8003 serveo.net
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now running `systemctl status server-tunnels` says it failed due to bad setting.

---

I'm very new to services and the Raspberry PI, so maybe I missed something obvious.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try adding ExecStart= before the ExecStart you have in the service file. And perhaps change the Type=simple to Type=oneshot. Honestly I cannot remember why to use oneshot.

Comment: Please dont't give the solution in the question. This does not finish the question. Instead you should write an answer. Just move the solution from the question into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I solved it:
I installed the npm module localtunnel which allows me to tunnel my localhost to network without ssh. The new service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Server Tunneling
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=lt --port 8003 --subdomain server-login
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!**

Comment: You do not need `Type=simple`. That's default. Your program will go to the background as as service. So why to use `Restart=always`? Do you suspect that your started program is buggy and fails to run? Then to restart it always is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should place your unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/server-tunnels.service`, not `/lib/systemd/system/server-tunnels.service`. The directory under `/etc` is intended for the local administrator while the directory under `/lib` is intended for the distribution.

The reason why the command doesn't work it that it doesn't know how to log in. Commands started as a service don't have access to the terminal, so `ssh` can't ask for a password. They also have a limited environment, so `ssh` doesn't know how to connect to your `ssh-agent` if you have it running. It can access your unencrypted SSH keys in the standard locations, but you don't seem to have them. f you have a key in a non-standard location, you can use option `-i` to specify the file. If your key is encrypted you again have the problem that `ssh` can't ask for the decryption password.

So if you want this to work, you need an unencrypted SSH key to log in to the server.

Comment: This ssh server doesn't require login

Comment: What does that mean? No user name? No password?

Comment: Just run the comand